# Finding the radii that maximizes and minimizes the area of four inscribed circles in an equilateral triangle.

Tags: calculus, geometry, optimization, triangles, circles

> [image]
>
> An equilateral triangle with side length $1$ unit contains three identical circles $C_1$, $C_2$ and $C_3$ of radius $r_1$, each touching two sides of the triangle. A fourth circle $C4$ of radius $r_2$ touches each of $C_1$, $C_2$ and $C_3$ as shown. Except for the contact points with $C_4$, none of the circles have any points in common with any of the other circles. Determine the values of $r_1$ and $r_2$ which minimize and maximize the sum $S$ of the areas of the four circles.

**My attempt:**

To maximize the area, I figured that I had to maximize the equation $S = 3\pi r_{1}^2 + \pi r_{2}^2$ by setting its derivative to zero and solving for $r_{1}$, then $r_{2}$. In order to change this formula so that I only had to work with $r_{1}$, I concluded after some experimentation that I could use $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} = 3r_{1}+r_{2}$ to substitute terms, where $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ is the distance between the vertex and the circumcenter. I got that $r_{2} = 3r_{1} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$. Following this process, I had $S = \pi(12r_{1}^2-2\sqrt{3}r_{1} + \frac{1}{3}), \frac{dS}{dr_{1}} = 24r_{1}-2\sqrt{3}$, and finally got a final answer of $r_{1} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{12}$.

However, this result made my $r_{2}$ value negative, and then I got really stuck with what I was doing. I tried thinking it out, such as trying to figure out the domains and finding other equations to use, but I seem to be blanking out with this question. I'm now even more confused how I am supposed to find the values that result in the minimum $S$. Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: How do you get the result "$3r_1+r_2=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$"?

Comment: @Doubtnut I considered the distance $L$ between the top vertex and the circumcenter. For a triangle with a = 1, this distance is $1/\sqrt{3}$, which can be found by applying the Pythagorean theorem. I thought that I could write this distance in terms of the radii. I initially had $1/\sqrt{3} = r_{2} + 2r_{1} + x$, and I didn't know what $x$ was. However, I observed that this $x$ was the same as $r_{1}$, no matter what value it was. I can't absolutely guarantee this to be true, but I recall seeing a problem where this had to be proven.

Comment: Please show how did you get $x=r_1$.

Comment: I don't have any experience with doing geometric proofs so instead, I did coordinate geometry on desmos to see if my observation had any potential truth to it, and it did. The line that connected the vertex and the circumcenter together was certainly split into two equal parts by the circle's tangent. I know this is true because I used the distance formula for each segment and they were the same. I would show a geometric proof of this if I could.

Answer (score 2):

It is true that $\frac{1}{\sqrt3} = 3r_1+r_2$, although you seem not to have a proof of this fact.
But it does not follow that $r_2 \stackrel?= 3r_1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt3}.$
You have made a mistake in your algebra there, although once you square the expression for $r_2$ the mistake is canceled out.

A more serious mistake is when you thought that $r_1 = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{12}$ would maximize $\pi(12r_1^2-  2\sqrt3 r_1 + \frac13)$.
Instead, it gives a minimum.

But the real trick here is to figure out how large $r_1$ can be before the figure can no longer satisfy the description.
Here I would argue that the problem is ill-stated, because the configuration where the $r_1$ circles just touch each other is forbidden by the problem statement, yet it has a smaller area than any configuration in which the circles do not touch, and any of those configurations can be given less area by making the $r_1$ circles a little larger (just not quite large enough to touch). Hence no allowed configuration minimizes the area; it's like asking for the smallest value of $x$ such that $x > 1.$

On the other end, the problem does not say if the $r_2$ circle is required to be entirely contained in the triangle. If it is not, the area is maximized when 
$r_1 = 0,$ provided that you consider a circle of radius $0$ to be a circle.
If the $r_2$ circle is limited to be inside the triangle then the minimum value of $r_1$ is larger than zero.

---

If I had to guess what the author meant, I would guess that they did not really mean to prevent the $r_1$ circles from touching, merely that they could not overlap, and I would guess that they meant the $r_2$ circle to be contained within (but possibly tangent to) the triangle.
That gives you minimum and maximum values of $r_1.$
You will note that the value of $r_1$ that sets $dS/dr_1$ to zero is not in that range.
You should know something about finding minima and maxima of a function when the domain is bounded, which you can then apply to this problem.

Comment: That really does help me view the problem a little differently and clear up some of the confusion I had with the question itself. Just so I understand, I need to focus on the domains of the two radii and then use that information as I analyze $dS/dr_{1}$ to determine the minimum and maximum? Was my process for determining $dS/dr_{1}$ right? (excluding the algebra mistakes, which I'm surprised I didn't catch)

Comment: You got the correct derivative (through a correct method except for that one sign error, which canceled out) and correctly identified when it is zero. This is useful information even when the domain is bounded and even when the zero of the derivative is outside the domain.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should formulate an optimization problem and solve it using KKT conditions.

The objective function $f(r_1,r_2)=\pi(3r_1^2+r_2^2)$

The equality constraint $h(r_1,r_2)=3r_1+r_2-1/\sqrt 3=0$

The inequality constraint $g(r_1,r_2)=r_2-\sqrt{5/4}+1/\sqrt 3 \leq 0$.

The last constraint aims to limit the circle to be inside the triangle.

Answer (score 0):

$r_1$ varies from $\min(r_1)=\tfrac{\sqrt3}{18}$,
when $r_2$ is equal the inradius $r=\tfrac{\sqrt3}6$,
to $\max(r_1)=\tfrac14\,(\sqrt3-1)$, when all the four circles 
are mutually tangent to each other.

The value of $r_2$ can be expressed in terms of 
$r_1$ and $r$ as
\begin{align}
r_2(r_1)&=2r-3r_1
,
\end{align}

hence the objective function 
is
\begin{align} 
f(r_1)&=
\pi\,(3r_1^2+r_2(r_1)^2)
=4\pi\,(3r_1^2-3\,r\,r_1+r^2)
,\\
f'(r_1)&=12\,\pi\,(2r_1-r)
,
\end{align}

so the objective function is a parabola 
and on the interval of interest 
it has the minimum at $r_1=\tfrac12\,r=\tfrac{\sqrt3}{12}$
(all the four circles has the same radius)
and the maximum at $r_1=\min(r_1)=\tfrac{\sqrt3}{18}$.